# DataTables Server-side Processing with web2py: how to access the parameters sent to the server

Tags: datatables, web2py

When using server-side Ajax processing for DataTables, DataTables sends parameters from the view to the server so that the server can access the data source and return the correct data. I cannot figure out how, when doing server-side processing with web2py, to access those parameters that comes from the view.

These parameters are, for example, iDisplayStart, IDisplayLength, iColumns, etc.and are documented here: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side

I have no doubt this is simple and will result in a loud "doh!" from me, but I have been digging around for a couple days and haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web2py, variables from a POST request are in `request.post_vars`, variables from the query string are in `request.get_vars`, and both sets of variables are in `request.vars`. So, in your controller, you can access those variables via `request.vars.iDisplayStart`, `request.vars.iDisplayLength`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony. Once again you come to the rescue for me!